# Apollo/GraphQL error: Identifier Name Violation: Variable name should only contain alphanumeric characters '__typename' (identifier_name)

Tags: swift, xcode, graphql, cocoapods, apollo

I am using GraphQL within my Swift project. I have installed Apollo through CocoaPods, and I have added a schema.json file to my project.  However, I keep getting errors all over my project.  The error I am currently dealing with is within `API.swift`, a file that is autogenerated by Apollo.  The file contains auto-generated variables, "__typename", which will always be there because Apollo seems to re-generate this at compile-time (in other words, I cannot simply delete these declarations of "__typename").

I am continually getting this error all over my `API.swift` file:

> Variable name should only contain alphanumeric characters '__typename' (identifier_name)

Does anyone know why this is? My friend has a project with this exact same implementation (his API.swift file has the exact same variable names), and it works!  Is there something wrong with Apollo on my machine?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you managed to get this resolved? Which version of Xcode and Apollo are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issues and discovered that my project was making use of [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint). Please check if you are using SwiftLint in your pod file.

One of the default enabled SwiftLint rules [Identifier Name](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/Source/SwiftLintFramework/Rules/Style/IdentifierNameRule.swift) is causing the Identifier Name Violation error message within the automatically generated Apollo GraphQL API.swift file.

Description of the Identifier Name rule:

> Identifier names should only contain alphanumeric characters and start with a lowercase character or should only contain capital letters. In an exception to the above, variable names may start with a capital letter when they are declared static and immutable. Variable names should not be too long or too short.

You have 2 options to disable this rule.

**Option 1: Disable the rule for your complete project**:

If you don’t want to use specific SwiftLint rule(s) for your project then you can disable those rules completely by adding and [configuring](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#configuration) .swiftlint.yml in your xcode project.

```
disabled_rules: # rule identifiers to exclude from running

  - identifier_name
```

**Option 2: Disable rule at file level**

Add disable [comment](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#disable-rules-in-code) above the line that throws the error with '__typename'.

```
// swiftlint:disable:this identifier_name
```

I would suggest to use **option 1** because option 2 will require you to disable the Generate Apollo GraphQL API Build Phase as this will re-generate your API.swift file.

My setup:

- Xcode: Version 12.4
- Mac OS X: Version: 10.15.7
- Apollo: apollo/2.33.4 darwin-x64 node-v12.18.3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried disable the rule for your complete project, however there were also other warnings for swiftlint, so I used path exclusion for **swiflint**. You can make use of the configuration file **.swiftlint.yml** by specifying the paths you want to exclude in the excluded section of the configuration, you can effectively disable **SwiftLint** for those paths.

Here's an example of how to configure .swiftlint.yml:

```
excluded: # paths to ignore during linting. overridden by `included`.
 - Services/GraphQL
```